# Problema con form y rutas en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6

Error
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Estoy realizando una pagina pero al realizar un formulario post me esta regresando ese error.

les comparto la ruta  y el form

```
<form name='formchangelanguages' action="login" method="post">
                  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> 
                 <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="{{ $ids }}">
                 <input type="hidden" name="eshi" id="eshi" value="es">
</form>
```

Esta es la ruta

```
  <?php



////////////////////Loguin/////////////////////////////  
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@showlogin');  
Route::get('L/{value}','Auth\LoginController@loginauto');

///////////////Rpouts TEST////////////
Route::get('mail', function(){
    return view('mailGenealogy');
}); 

Route::get('error', 'Controller@error');

Route::get('subirDatoswoot', 'Controller@subirDatoswoot');
```

Comment: Esa forma de declarar la ruta en el action será muy difícil de mantener, prueba usar el helper route y a tu ruta dale un nombre

Comment: Tienes más rutas definidas?

Comment: @BetaM Si tengo muchas rutas mas definidas. y  probare así como  me indicas.

Comment: De lo que obtengas edita y te ayudamos

Comment: @BetaM estas son algunas rutas,  no pude publicar mas ya que son muchas y no me deja editarlo  con todas.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es por que te está faltando el toquen `@csrf`

> Cada que definas un `HTML form` en tu aplicación, deberás incluir un campo de `token` oculto `CSRF` en el `form` para que el `middleware` de protección `CRSF` pueda validar la solicitud.
> Deberás usar la directiva `@csrf` de `Blade` para generar el campo de `token`:
>
> ```
> <form method="POST" action="/profile">
>     @csrf
>     ...
> </form>
> ```
>
> [CSRF protection - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-introduction)

Yo tengo esto en un proyecto y no me sale ese error

```
<form action="contacto/contacto" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-grup-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" for="nombre">Nombre</span>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" type="text">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <label class="input-group-text" for="mail">Correo electrónico</label>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" name="mail" id="mail" type="email">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <label class="input-group-text" for="subject">Asunto</label>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" type="text">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mensaje">Mensaje</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="c_asunto" id="mensaje" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-outline-secondary col-md-12 col-lg-1" type="submit">Enviar</button> 
    </div>
</form>
```

web.php

```php
Route::post('contacto/contacto','contacto@contacto');
```

Comment: Si tengo  agregado  el  token en el  formulario.